# Hacer funcionar el sistema de inscripción (HTML+PHP+SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de inscripción básico con HTML, PHP y SQL... al final al inscribir a una persona me lanza el siguiente resultado:

```
0) { echo ("
cedula ya registrada.
"); } else { $insertar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumno_inscrito VALUES ({$cedula},'{$pnombre}','{$snombre}','{$papellido}','{$sapellido}','{$correo}','{$telefCompleto}','{$tipo}')", $conexion); echo("
"); echo ("
Registro realizado con éxito.
"); echo ("
Gracias =)
"); echo ("
"); echo ("
"); } if (!$insertar) { echo("
"); echo ("
"); die("
Error interno. Contacte al administrador
"); echo ("
"); } //Cerrar conexión a la Base de Datos mysql_close($conexion); ?>
```

Deseo saber cuál es la falla para que me funcione bien... gracias de antemano por su ayuda

**Este es index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script> 
        function revisar() {
            if(document.formulario.cedula.value == "") { alert('Revisa la cédula') ; return false ; }
            if(document.formulario.pnombre.value == "") { alert('Debes poner el 1er nombre') ; return false ; }
            if(document.formulario.snombre.value == "") { alert('Debes poner el 2do nombre') ; return false ; }
            if(document.formulario.papellido.value == "") { alert('Debes poner el 1er apellido') ; return false ; }
            if(document.formulario.sapellido.value == "") { alert('Debes poner el 2do apellido') ; return false ; }
            if(document.formulario.correo.value == ""){ alert('Ingrese correo válido'); return false; }
            if(document.formulario.telef.value == "") { alert('Ingresa número'); return false;}
            else{return true;}
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <title>Registro</title>

    <h1 align = 'center'>Sistema de Inscripción</h1>

    <h2 align = 'center'>Bellydancers Crew</h2>

    <hr><br>

    <form name="formulario" action="registro.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return revisar();">

        <table border=1 align=center width="27%" >
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>CÉDULA:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="cedula" size="18"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>1er NOMBRE:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="pnombre" size="18"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>2do NOMBRE:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="snombre" size="18"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>1er APELLIDO:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="papellido" size="18"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>2do APELLIDO:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="sapellido" size="18"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>CORREO:</b></td><td><input type="text" name="correo" size="18"></input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><b>NRO. TELÉFONO CELULAR:</b></td>
                        <td><select type"text" name="operadora">
                                <option value=0416>0416</option>
                                <option value=0426>0426</option>
                                <option value=0414>0414</option>
                                <option value=0424>0424</option>
                                <option value=0412>0412</option>
                            </select>

                            <input name="telef" type="text" size=8></input>

                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right ><b>ROL:</b></td><td>

                        <select name=tipo>
                            <option value=Estudiante>Estudiante</option>
                            <option value=Representante>Representante</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>


                <tr>

                <!--<td><div style="margin-top:3%"> <input name="registrar" type="submit" value="Registrar" /></div></td>
                <td><div style="margin-top:3%"> <input name="limpiar" type="submit" value="Limpiar" /></div></td>
                -->
                <!--<td><div><input type=submit value=Prueba name=1 align="center"></input></div></td><td><input type=submit value=Registrar name=registrar><input type=submit value=Cancelar align = 'center'></input></td>-->

                <td colspan="2"><center><input type=submit value="Registrar" name="registro" ></input><input type="reset" value="Limpiar"></input></center></td>
                </tr>

        </table>
    </form>

    <hr><p align="center">HJRL 2020</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Este es REGISTRO.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script>
            function mensaje(){
                alert('Error');
                }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>

<?php
    //Crear conexión a la Base de Datos
    $conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","root","LACONTRASEÑA");
    if (!$conexion)
        {
            die("Fallo la conexión a la Base de Datos: " . mysql_error());
        }

    //Seleccionar la Base de Datos a utilizar
    $seleccionar_bd = mysql_select_db("inscripcion", $conexion);
    if (!$seleccionar_bd)
        {
            die("Fallo la selección de la Base de Datos: " . mysql_error());
        }

    //Tomar los campos provenientes del Formulario
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $pnombre = $_POST['pnombre'];
    $snombre = $_POST['snombre'];
    $papellido = $_POST['papellido'];
    $sapellido = $_POST['sapellido'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $operadora = $_POST['operadora'];
    $telf = $_POST['telef'];

    $telefCompleto = $operadora . $telf;

    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];


    //Insertar campos en la Base de Datos
    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT cedula FROM alumno_inscrito WHERE cedula = {$cedula}");
    $total_encontrado = mysql_num_rows($consulta);

    if ($total_encontrado > 0)
        {
            echo ("<h3 align='center'>cedula ya registrada. </h3>");
        }
    else
        {
            $insertar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumno_inscrito VALUES ({$cedula},'{$pnombre}','{$snombre}','{$papellido}','{$sapellido}','{$correo}','{$telefCompleto}','{$tipo}')", $conexion);
            echo("<center>");
            echo ("<h3>Registro realizado con éxito.</h3>");
            echo ("<h3>Gracias =)</h3>");
            echo ("<form name='form2' action='index.php'><input type='submit' value='Regristrar otro usuario'></input>
            </form>");
            echo ("</center>");
        }

    if (!$insertar)
        {
            echo("<center>");
            echo ("<form name='form3' action='index.php'><input type='submit' value='Regresar a página de registro'></input>
            </form>");
            die("<h4>Error interno. Contacte al administrador</h4>");
            echo ("</center>");
        }

    //Cerrar conexión a la Base de Datos
    mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

**ESTE ES estatus.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <h1 align="center">Lista de Inscritos =)</h1><hr><br>

    <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2 style="font-size: 12pt">
        <tr>
            <td><font face="verdana"><b>Cedula</b></font></td>
            <td><font face="verdana"><b>Nombre</b></font></td>
            <td><font face="verdana"><b>Apellido</b></font></td>
        </tr>

</html>

<?php 
  $link = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root","TU CONTRASEÑA) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");

  @mysql_select_db("inscripcion", $link) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");

  $query = "SELECT cedula, pnombre, snombre, papellido, sapellido FROM alumno_inscrito order by cedula";

  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $numero = 0;

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . $row["cedula"] . "</font></td>";
        echo "<td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . $row["pnombre"] . $row["snombre"] . "</font></td>";
        echo "<td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana\">" . $row["papellido"] . $row["sapellido"] . "</font></td>";

        $numero++;
    }

    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"15\"><font face=\"verdana\"><b>Numero de Inscritos: " . $numero . "</b></font></td></tr>";

    mysql_free_result($result);

    mysql_close($link);
?>
</table>
```

**ESTA ES MI BASE DE DATOS**

```
CREATE DATABASE `inscripcion`
USE `inscripcion`;
CREATE TABLE `alumno_inscrito` (
  `cedula` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `pnombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `snombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `papellido` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `sapellido` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cedula`));
```

Answer (score 0):

a primer impresion el problema puede ser:

en el archivo registro.php tu conexion:

```
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost","root","LACONTRASEÑA");
```

el 3 atributo debe estar vacio ("") sino haz cambiado la contraseña por default para el mysql

en el archivo status.php tu conexion:

```
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root","TU CONTRASEÑA) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");
```

el 3 atributo debe estar vacio ("") si no haz cambiado la contraseña por default para el mysql
te falta cerrar las comillas

- ambos archivos no tienen la misma contraseña de usuario para mysql, revisalo ambos tiene que coincidir

Comment: Exacto BetaM deberia cambiar el @mysql_connect por el mysqli

Comment: Ya hice los cambios y sigue arrojando el mismo resultado... :-(